# Get full path from the folder only without starting with c:\

Tags: vb.net

So this code only gives me folder names. I need to get both folder and file names without the C:... :

```
Sub GetDirectories(ByVal StartPath As String)

        For Each Dir As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(StartPath)

            ListBox1.Items.AddRange(IO.Directory.GetFiles(StartPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))

        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Label1_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles Label1.DragDrop

        ListBox1.Items.Clear()

        Dim files() As String = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)

        For Each path In files

            For Each Dir As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path)

                GetDirectories(path)

            Next

        Next

        ListBox2.Items.Clear()

        For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

            ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items(i).ToString)

        Next

        Label5.Text = ListBox1.Items.Count

        Label1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(224, 224, 224)

    End Sub
```

how its look:

```
C:\Users\Shai\Desktop\New folder\input\text.txt
C:\Users\Shai\Desktop\New folder\input\folder\app.py
```

now im looking for something like that without starting with c:\ or the continue of that, just the folder name and move on:

```
text.txt
folder\app.py
```

Comment: You're asking us how to get a substring from a `String`? Surely not.

Comment: im trying to get that resualt:

newfolder/x.png,
newfolder/newfolder2/xx.png,
newfolder/newfolder2/test.txt

in my list when i drag the folder call "newfolder".

Comment: Yeah, and that's a substring of the `String` containing the full path. That's the point: you ARE asking us how to get a substring. You don't need us to tell you that. You can work it out for yourself.

Comment: Looks like you are chopping off the "vs" folder, too.  Your rules are inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

The Directory.GetFiles method ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles)) returns the names of files that meet specified criteria.

One option that you have is to massage the data coming in from the GetFiles method to get everything after the value returned from Path.GetPathRoot ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getpathroot)).

Take a look at this example:

```vb
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(IO.Directory.GetFiles(StartPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(Function(filename) filename.Substring(IO.Path.GetPathRoot(filename).Length)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Path Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=net-5.0) to get the root directory:

```
Dim root As String = Path.GetPathRoot(filename)
```

then just remove it from:

```
Dim withoutRoot As String = filename.Remove(0, root.Length)
```

or Substring it:

```
Dim withoutRoot As String = filename.Substring(root.Length)
```